# Problems about accessing Kotlin companion object in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, kotlin

I want to get the instance of this Interface  `KotlinDecompilerService` https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/idea/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/internal/KotlinDecompilerService.kt in Groovy.

I try:

```
final KotlinDecompilerService decompilerService = 
KotlinDecompilerService.Companion.getInstance()
```

But the Groovy `KotlinDecompilerService.Companion` returns a `java.lang.Class` instance.
(The static field and the class have the same name `Companion`)

```
2017-06-24 23:31:59,066 [9849885]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot cast object 'class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinDecompilerService$Companion' with class 'java.lang.Class' to class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinDecompilerService$Companion' 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinDecompilerService$Companion' with class 'java.lang.Class' to class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinDecompilerService$Companion'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:319)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:232)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:603)
```

I have to use reflection to get the instance.

```
final KotlinDecompilerService decompilerService = 
KotlinDecompilerService.Companion.newInstance().getInstance()
```

It works, but I just wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 24):

you can access member fields directly by `@` since it always ref the class rather than its instance in groovy. for example:

```
def decompilerService = KotlinDecompilerService.@Companion.instance
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it just does not work. Maybe in Java, this works. But Groovy is different.

Comment: This is the only way I was able to access the companion object from Groovy.  In my case the error was 'groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Foo() is applicable for argument types

Comment: I was able to call a Companion method from Groovy with:  def foo = MyKotlinClass.@Companion.methodToCall(args)